# Apache Artemis - Apache Camel threaded consumer gets slow over time

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis, spring-camel

I am running Apache Artemis Broker 2.14.0. Below is the consumer connection configuration:

```xml
<beans
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
      
   <bean class="com.test.CustomProcessBean" id="CustomProcessBean" scope="prototype"/>
   
   <bean id="jmsCF" class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
      <property name="remoteURI"  value="ampq://myhost:5672"/>
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="jmsPooledCF" class="org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
      <property name="maxConnections" value="3" />
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsCF" />
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledCF" />
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
      <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10" />
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
      <property name="transacted" value="true" />
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="errHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
      <property name="deadLetterUri" value="jms:queue:customDLQ"/>
      <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="customRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
   </bean>
   
   <bean id="customRedeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
      <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3"/>
      <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="8000"/>
   </bean>
   
   <camelContext id="camel"
      xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <endpoint id="etams" uri="jms:queue:test-queue" />
      <route errorHandlerRef="errHandler" >
         <from uri="ref:etams"/>
         <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
         <threads id="threadedprocess" maxQueueSize="5" poolSize="5" maxPoolSize="5" customId="true" >
            <bean ref="CustomProcessBean" method="processMessage"/>
         </threads>
      </route>
   </camelContext>
   
</beans>
```

To begin with the route was processing ~100 message-per-second. Over time (~6 hrs) it dropped to ~25 messages-per-second.

From the "Consumers" tab in the Artemis web console I noticed each session is closed and created often.

From the broker side we had provided enough memory 12G. The broker runs with persistence enabled, and the incoming message size are less than 5kb.

Does the Camel `threads` try to create more session over time? Is this an anti-pattern? Is this the reason for consumer to process the messages slow overtime? When I don't use the Camel `threads` in the configuration (i.e. just `<bean ref="CustomProcessBean ...>`) I noticed the session ID created are NOT changing. This might be totally based on the use case, but does re-creating the sessions cause performance stress on broker?

Comment: I infer that whenever the consumer tab is refreshed the hash Id value is changing.

Comment: I understand the consumer (uses AMQP client) configuration is recreating the sessions. When I don't use the camel thread in configuration (just <bean ref="CustomProcessBean ..>), I noticed the session Id created are NOT changing.  This might be totally based on the use case. But re-creating the sessions - does this cause performance stress on broker ?

Comment: broker runs with persistence enabled and the incoming message size are less than 5kb's.

Comment: To begin with it was  ~100 message-per-second, over time (~6 hrs) it is ~25 messages-per-second. One observation is the consumer count keeps on varying between 1 to 10 ( 10 is set maxconcurrentconsumer value)
Camel thread was used only after fetching the messages from the queue.

Comment: If you remove the use of Camel `threads` do you still see the performance degradation? Also, it's still not clear *why* you started using `threads` in the first place.

Comment: If I increase the consumer count I see the messages are getting processed at a better rate now. Not sure if network traffic issues either.

I can remove the threads there it shouldn't impact our Requirement either.

Comment: Why are you using the AMQ component with Artemis? AMQ is for the older AMQ. Use Jms, Sjms or the Sjms2 comoponent rather. The camel documents even say this somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and solved it by setting `cacheLevelName` option in the JMS endpoint to `CACHE_CONSUMER`. By enabling the `transacted` option, you end up setting cache level to `CACHE_NONE`.

This section will explain you better: [JMS Component - TRANSACTIONS AND CACHE LEVELS](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_transactions_and_cache_levels)